# Conditional selection in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL code:

```
SELECT eml AS "Email Address"
FROM emailtbl
WHERE DEPT LIKE 'E%'
```

My issue is that if the department starts in 'F' I must select fax instead of eml. What could I do to select eml if the dept starts with 'E' and select fax if the dept starts in 'F'

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to use a `UNION ALL` statement

```
SELECT eml AS "Entity"
FROM   emailtbl
WHERE  DEPT LIKE 'E%'
UNION ALL
SELECT fax AS "Entity"
FROM   emailtbl
WHERE  DEPT LIKE 'F%'
```

another one is to use a `CASE`statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Dept LIKE 'E%' THEN eml ELSE fax END AS "Entity"
FROM   emailtbl
WHERE  DEPT LIKE 'E%' OR DEPT LIKE 'F%'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
IF (SUBSTRING(@useLike,1,1) = 'E')
BEGIN
    SELECT eml AS "Email Address"
    FROM emailtbl
    WHERE DEPT LIKE @useLike

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT fax AS "Email Address"
    FROM emailtbl
    WHERE DEPT LIKE @useLike
END
```

Comment: Actually now the page has refreshed; Lieven anwser is pretty cool.

Comment: You mean to say it wasn't before? ;)